# Quickly make a static linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to quickly make a static linked list, with as little code as possible, which is very readable and without clutter. How do i accomplish this elegantly?

something like

`1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> NULL`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
struct node {int x; struct node *next;};
#define cons(x,next) (struct node[]){{x,next}}
struct node *head = cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, cons(4, NULL))));
```

Comment: @ArjunSreedharan.: Please explain the 2nd line.

Comment: @amalsom the array has only 1 element which contains the integer `x` and the pointer `next`. Here the `next` would be the address of the next `node[]` or `NULL`.

Comment: @ArjunSreedharan.: How is it possible that a statement like `(struct node[]){{x,next}}` be syntactically correct. Is this statement a initialization. Can you give example of something similar to this used in C language normally?

Comment: Yes, there is definitively one pair of `{}` too much.