# How does this code actually work?

Tags: c, linked-list

I can't understand this 3 line code used to implement **static linked list**. This is actually the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192284/quickly-make-a-static-linked-list/29192292).

I am posting the code here again-(the main action is basically the 2nd line)

```
struct node {int x; struct node *next;};
#define cons(x,next) (struct node[]){{x,next}}
struct node *head = cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, cons(4, NULL))));
```

My question is - what is the functionality of this statement?
`(struct node[]){{x,next}}`. Is this a initialization statement and what is it returning that it can be assigned to a `struct node*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(struct node[]){{x,next}}` is a compound literal and it will initialize a `struct *node` pointer.

```
+------+------+     +------+------+     +------+------+     +------+------+
|      |      |     |      |      |     |      |      |     |      |      |
|  1   | next +---->|  2   | next +---->|  3   | next +---->|  4   | NULL |
|      |      |     |      |      |     |      |      |     |      |      |
+------+------+     +------+------+     +------+------+     +------+------+
   ^
   |
  head
```

Comment: It can be written as `#define cons(x,next) (struct node*) {x,next}` why did he use the extra parenthesis? probably redundant then.

Comment: And  the memory is allocated from the stack memory not from heap as no dynamic allocation is used.

Comment: There is no cast. It may look like a one, but `( ){ }` is simply the compound-literal operator.

Comment: This was a bad question? I simply didn't know at that time. Still it is being DVed.

Comment: @sg7.: Well it is compound literal. And this use is nice, but the author in the original answer from which I referred only added code-only answer. That's evoked the question.